# How to say an animal (tiger, cat..) or poultry (chicken, duck) are saying?

Tags: word-choice

what is the general word that expresses that an animal (tiger, cat..) or poultry (chicken, duck) are saying.

We say "*human talks*" and what about other animals and poultry?

Example, "*a cat meows*", "*a tiger .....*", "a *chicken ....*", "*a duck ....*".

So:
*Is there any general word that expresses that an animal (tiger, cat..) or poultry (chicken, duck) are saying?*

Comment: Are you looking for a general word that covers ALL animal noises, from moos to baas to barks to honks?

Answer (score 3):

Tigers roar, chickens cluck, ducks quack. If you want one word, animals communicate via *vocalization*.   Animals *vocalize*.

http://news.discovery.com/animals/insects/largest-archive-of-animal-sounds-now-available-online-130116.htm

Comment: Okay, but [what does the fox say](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jofNR_WkoCE)? (*Sorry, couldn't resist...*)

Comment: One good turn deserves another :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrVgtb-LYX4

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on exactly what's being asked, but the word *goes* is relevant here:

- The cow goes 'moo.'
- The duck goes 'quack.'